# Что может служить уникальным идентификатором ПК и как его получить в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Уже много ищу по интернету по поводу этого. Самое часто-предлагаемое: использовать *UUID* или же парсить ответ команды *wmic*. Однако UUID клонируется, если делать виртуальные машины и заливать туда файлы от 1 виртуалки, более того, его можно просто указать при создании эдакой (потому *mac-адрес* так же отпадает), а wmic можно отключить в принципе, что приведет к ошибке.

Я склоняюсь к попытке получить уникальный идентификатор процессора/видеочипа, "напрямую". Возможно ли это сделать в python?

OS: Windows 10.

Comment: Во-первых, при желании всё это тоже можно сэмулировать в виртуальной машине. Во-вторых, если пользователь захочет купить себе новый процессор/видеочип — он начнёт вас люто ненавидеть

Comment: серийный номер процессора получить довольно сложно. серийный номер харда проще. но единственный современный способ это онлайн активация

Comment: @andreymal, аудитория у программки не такая большая, что бы процессоры менялись часто. Я бы сказал, возможно раз, максимум 2.